# Named and default exports in one declaration

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Suppose I have a library `math-utils` that exports some functions `add`, `subtract`, etc.

I would like it to be usable like this:

```
import { add, subtract } from 'math-utils';

add(1, 2);
```

But I would also like it to be usable like this:

```
import MathUtils from 'math-utils';

MathUtils.add(1, 2);
```

I can achieve this using exports like this:

```
export const add = (x, y) => x + y;

export const subtract = (x, y) => x + y;

export default {
  add, 
  subtract, 
};
```

How can I get this behaviour in one `export` declaration?

Comment: Simple is change your spec and replace If it's ok for you:
import MathUtils from 'math-utils';
replace:
import * as MathUtils from 'math-utils';

Answer (score 0):

You can import them all using

```
import * as MathUtils from 'math-utils';
```

So if you have a default method in the `math-utils`, you just have to use `MathUtils.default`

Comment: I don't want to import them all, just a fixed list.

Comment: @sdgfsdh I do not think there is a way for what you ask except for your own solution. You can however, export different objects for different files you are importing them on. For example , make `objFile_your_file = { your_functions_used_by_your_file} ` I do not know if that is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a default export. Named exports are best suited for your use case.

> But I would also like it to be usable like an object

Then use

```
import * as MathUtils from 'math-utils';
MathUtils.add(1, 2);
```

with your named exports.